# Best and concise resources/links for learning SEO techniques?

Tags: search, seo, search-engine

Can you suggest any quick and concise resources for learning SEO techniques?

Comment: Build a website that's usable and accessible with quality content. That 99% of SEO right there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beyond John's comment - which is TRUE, here is a list I have compiled (see the rest at http://www.qnq.com.au/resources/online-seo-link-repository/)

In no particular order and with no favour:

- http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf
- https://docs.google.com/Present?docid=dc3qhbxg_1217d9mwjwg3
- http://www.bruceclay.com/web_rank.htm
- http://www.websitepublisher.net/seo-guide/
- http://www.highrankings.com/tentips
- http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/seo/
- http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2007/10/how-to-create-1.html
- http://www.webconfs.com/15-minute-seo.php
- http://www.seomoz.org/blog/the-web-developers-seo-cheat-sheet
- http://www.conversationmarketing.com/2010/07/on-page-seo-cheatsheet.htm
- http://www.seo-theory.com/wordpress/2008/09/22/nine-lessons-in-search-engine-optimization/
- http://searchengineland.com/25-super-common-seo-mistakes-51888
- http://www.seobook.com/archives/001792.shtml
- http://www.seobook.com/seo-strategy
- http://www.bing.com/community/blogs/webmaster/archive/2009/06/26/site-architecture-and-seo-file-page-issues-sem-101.aspx
- http://www.searchenginejournal.com/bing-rankings-cheat-sheet/29847/
- http://blog.vkistudios.com/index.cfm/2009/9/2/Server-Status-Codes-and-SEO
- http://sixrevisions.com/content-strategy/user-friendly-seo/
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecI_hCBGEIM – great 1hr long
  presentation from Google

Make it through that list, and you'll be well on your way.

Remember - ***“Knowing is not enough; we must apply!”*** – Goethe